# Why my client IP address shows different IP's every time?

Tags: sql-server, azure, firewall

I am on `VPN` and trying to connect `Azure SQL server` from `SQL Management Studio`

I get this popup, but `IP` on it keep changes.

[image]

Because of this, I see a lot of IP's getting added in `Firewall` settings of SQL Server in Azure portal

What is the solution here?
Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a static IP address by your provider?

Comment: Not sure. So you mean public IP keep changes? but in browser, if i search  "My IP" it always gives same IP.

Comment: I'm wondering if your "My IP" search is caching. Also, do the IPs in question fall into a range? It's possible your organization has a range of outbound public IPs.

Comment: In your screenshot, it seems that you've added a range of IP, can this make effect? Or need a bigger scope?

Comment: Hi @kudlatiger, I have the same environment that connect to the Azure SQL database via VPN connection. The client IP may changes every some days, I need to manually add the new IP to the firewall again manually. Just for now. I think that's caused by the VPN servers.Some suggestions are that keep your VPN address fixed.There isn't a good solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same environment that connect to the Azure SQL database via VPN connection. The client IP may changes every some days, I need to manually add the new IP to the firewall again manually. Just for now. I think that's caused by the VPN servers.Some suggestions are that keep your VPN address fixed. There isn't a good solution for now.

HTH.